# Unwanted characters appear in downloaded document name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wicked-pdf

I am generating PDF using WickedPDF gem but the issue I am facing is that the document which gets created has the document name as Document20200309-48764-1o1nyyu.pdf but the document name should be Document.pdf I am not sure why I am getting the characters after Document. Please help me resolve this problem.

```
pdf_file = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
        render_to_string(template: 'documents/document.pdf.erb',  locals: { payments: @payments }),
        formats: :html,
        encoding: "utf8",
        )

    if pdf_file.present?
      tempfile = Tempfile.new(["Document", '.pdf'], Rails.root.join('tmp'))
      tempfile.binmode
      tempfile.write pdf_file
      tempfile.close     
      tempfile.unlink
    end
```

Update

```
  path = "Documents"
  dir = File.dirname(path)
  unless File.directory?(dir)
    FileUtils.mkdir_p(dir)
  end
  path << ".pdf"
  file = File.new(path, 'w')
  file.write pdf_file
  @money.money_receipt = File.open(path)
  @money.save
  file.close
  file.unlink
```

Answer (score 2):

[Tempfile](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html) uses the first argument as a *prefix* to the generated filename. It adds additional characters to ensure a unique filename.

If you want a specific filename, consider using the regular file writer methods. You are responsible for unlinking the file afterwards, though, unless Tempfiles, which are unlinked when the Tempfile object is garbage collected.

Comment: Can you suggest me any regular file write method which will not cause this problem?

Comment: `File.open`? Just the regular file API.

Comment: Please check the update section in the question I am getting this error Failed to load PDF document.

Answer (score 0):

You created a path with document id `path = "Documents-#{@document.id}"`.

Then you added `.pdf` at the end of the path variable, then you use it to make a file name

```
path << ".pdf"
file = File.new(path, 'w')
```

If you write `file = File.new("Document.pdf")`, it would generate correct name